# Screen size integers. C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, methods, xna, int

I make a class `Resize.cs` and that takes an image from the `Images.cs` class and finds the width and height of the image by creating a new integer for each the width and height. I also make a resize to change the size of the image to fit the screen.

```
public static int resize = 1;

public static int backgroundWidth = resize * Images.Background.Width;
public static int backgroundHeight = resize * Images.Background.Height;
```

Then I take the width and height and move it over to the `Game1.cs` (The main class) and in the `public Game1()` I change the width and height of the screen, that works:

```
    public static int 768;
    public static int screenWidth = 1024;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = screenHeight;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = screenWidth; 
        graphics.IsFullScreen = false; 
        graphics.ApplyChanges();

        StartUp.Images.Content = Content;
    }
```

To:

```
    public static int screenHeight = StartUp.Resize.BackgroundHeight;
    public static int screenWidth = StartUp.Resize.BackgroundWidth;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = screenHeight;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = screenWidth; 
        graphics.IsFullScreen = false; 
        graphics.ApplyChanges();

        StartUp.Images.Content = Content;
    }
```

But no matter what I do, the Program.cs (That I never touch) comes up with an error: (This only happens when I start up the program it will say it is fine befor and after the program is started and ended)

TypeInitializationException was unhandled
 The type initializer for 'Love__Regret.Game1' threw an exception.

```
using System;

namespace **
{
#if WINDOWS || XBOX
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Game1 game = new Game1())
            {
                game.Run();
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

In the end my goal is to re size the screen at will inside the program. (because if 2 computers with different sizes of screen use the program it should fit correctly in both)

I inserted the regular numbers height = 100 and width = 157, they worked fine and resized the screen just as it should.

`Images.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace **.StartUp
{
    class Images
    {
        #region Define
        public static ContentManager Content;

        //TitleScreen
        public static Texture2D Background;
        public static Texture2D Continue;
        public static Texture2D Credits;
        public static Texture2D Exit;
        public static Texture2D Logo;
        public static Texture2D Options;
        public static Texture2D Play;
        public static Texture2D Version;
        //End

        //Options
        public static Texture2D OptionsLogo;
        public static Texture2D OffNotSelected;
        public static Texture2D OffSelected;
        public static Texture2D OnNotSelected;
        public static Texture2D OnSelected;
        public static Texture2D FullScreen;
        public static Texture2D Menu;
        public static Texture2D Music;
        public static Texture2D SliderBackground;
        public static Texture2D Slider;
        public static Texture2D SoundFX;
        //End
        #endregion

        #region Load
        public static void Load()
        {
            Background = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\StartUp\Background");
            Continue = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\StartUp\Continue");
            Credits = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\StartUp\Credits");
            Exit = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\StartUp\Exit");
            FullScreen = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\StartUp\FullScreen");
            Logo = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\StartUp\Logo");
            Menu = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\StartUp\Menu");
            Music = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\StartUp\Music");
            OffNotSelected = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\StartUp\OffNotSelected");
            OffSelected = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\StartUp\OffSelected");
            OnNotSelected = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\StartUp\OnNotSelected");
            OnSelected = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\StartUp\OnSelected");
            Options = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\StartUp\Options");
            OptionsLogo = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\StartUp\OptionsLogo");
            Play = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\StartUp\Play");
            Slider = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\StartUp\Slider");
            SliderBackground = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\StartUp\SliderBackground");
            SoundFX = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\StartUp\SoundFX");
            Version = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\StartUp\Version");
        }
        #endregion

        #region Method
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I load in the Images here(in `Game1.cs`):

```
protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            StartUp.Images.Load();
            font1 = Content.Load<SpriteFont>(@"Fonts\Font1");
        }
```

Comment: Did you inspect the values of `StartUp.Resize.BackgroundHeight` and `StartUp.Resize.BackgroundWidth` before setting the buffer dimensions?  It might be that those objects are not initialized properly. Where do you create/initialize the `Images.Background` object?

Comment: I have added the `LoadContent` and the `Images.cs`'s `Load` to show that the loading is correct.

Comment: I make the screenHeight and screenWidth a almost replica to the other image by making a resize inside the class and making it look like this: `static int resize = 16;` `public static int screenHeight = resize * 48;` and `public static int screenWidth = resize * 64; //divide by 16`

Comment: You are loading all the images in the `LoadContent` method, which gets fired after the `Game1` constructor. This means that you don't have any data in your `Images.Background` object. Therefore, your game doesn't get scaled.

Comment: Thank you sir, got to love it when some small error happens and I just don't notices. Thanks for the help.